# Палиндром в С++

Tags: c++, арифметика

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
 int x, b;
    cin >> x >> b;
    unsigned int x1 = x;
    int W = 0;
    for (int i=x; i <= b; x++) {
        while (x1 > 0) {
            W = W * 10 + x1 % 10;
            x1 = x1 / 10;

        }
        if (W == x) { cout << "True" << endl; }
        else { x1 = x1 + W; }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Не могу понять в чем ошибка,кто может поправить.Вот суть задания:Рассмотрим некоторое натуральное число N. если оно не является палиндромом, то построим новое число, изменив порядок цифр в записи числа N на обратный и добавим это новое число до N. Если полученная сумма не является палиндромом, то повторим с ней описаны действия., Пока не получим палиндром.
Проверить выполняется гипотеза Безу для чисел из промежутка [a, b] - Обратное число искать умеем

- проверять или число является палиндромом тоже
- Во внешнем цикле проходим по всем числам из промежутка [a, b] и проверяем выполняется гипотеза.

Comment: Не понимаю. "Всё умеем" - так что вам помогать?...

Comment: @Harry . ну почему то не работает

Comment: Что означает эта фраза: `и добавим это новое число до N` ?

Comment: @MBo тоесть до N добавим обратное число N

Comment: А, понял, к N прибавим перевернутое N  123:  125 + 521 = 646

Comment: @MBo да ,а в коде не получається,прохожу по промежутку и чет ниче

Comment: А теорема Безу тут причём? (она относится к алгебре многочленов)

Comment: @MBo  ой ето гипотеза

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119737/discussion-between-andrij-matviiv-and-mbo).

Answer (score 3):

Как я понимаю, нужно что-то типа

```
unsigned long long rev(unsigned long long n)
{
    unsigned long long m = 0;
    for(;n; n/=10) m = m*10+n%10;
    return m;
}

bool isPalindrome(unsigned long long n)
{
    if (n%10 == 0) return false;
    return rev(n) == n;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    unsigned long long a = 123, b = 201;
    for(int n = a; n <= b; ++n)
    {
        unsigned long long m = n;
        int count = 0;
        while(m < 1000000000000000000 && !isPalindrome(m))
        {
            m += rev(m);
            ++count;
        }
        if (m < 1000000000000000000)
            cout << "For " << n << " there are " << count << " steps needed\n";
        else
            cout << "For " << n << " there are too large numbers\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: На всякий случай (невиданного коварства препода;)) - на 196 срабатывает (видимо, из-за переполнения), а не должно.

Comment: @Harry, извини а без функций  как-то возможно?

Comment: @MBo , а как ето исправить?

Comment: @Andrij Matviiv https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Проблема_196  Не исключаю, что придётся использовать длинную арифметику и останавливаться после определённого числа шагов.

Comment: @MBo Я просто считаю, что проверять дальше 10^18 смысла нет - просто ведь невозможно проверять до бесконечности :) Код соответственно исправил.

Comment: @Harry Видимо, что-то подобное и ожидается.

Comment: @Harry а как сделать без функций?

Comment: @MBo а как ето сделать совсем без функций а то ето я не учил